# Error : org.openqa.selenium.ScriptTimeoutException: script timeout

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, google-chrome

I am using selenium webdriver with Java.  7/10 times my script failed with  error:

org.openqa.selenium.ScriptTimeoutException: script timeout

I tried so many option :

1. increase wait time
2. tried method jsWaitForPageToLoad and verified js.executeScript(""return document.readyState"").toString().equals("complete")
3. Wait for element to visible
4. wait for element to be Clickable
5. Wait last element to load

but nothing worked.

Workaround :  If I manually move my mouse little bit on browser then script work without issue.

As per above workaround,  I tried Action class to  move mouse also ,  but its not worked.

Env :  Chrome : Version 85.0.4183.83 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Selenium Webdriver : 3.141.59
Application : Developed in Angularjs

I also used ngwebdriver  (1.1.5) for angularJs

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue got fixed.  The issue was with waitForAngularRequestsToFinish() method of ngDriver.

Once I used as below :

ngDriver.withRootSelector(""root-app"").waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();

It worked well

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is a flaky one because of the front end technology used (angular js).

The best tool to automate agular web app is Protractor.