# Selenium and Java - script timeout on accessing every element on a page

Tags: java, selenium

I might be stupid, but I really don't get this at all. It's an Angular application, with a page on which the Selenium tests have been running fine up until now. Then a frontend developer did some markup changes (not quite sure what, but I wouldn't think it mattered as long as it's just html/markup and the page is working fine), and now nothing works.

And I mean nothing; Every Selenium operation, be it .elementVisible(), .click() or absolutely whatever, fails with a script timeout. No more details as far as I can see - it just times out. While the page is open, and every element is visible and interactable manually.

This is the script timeout error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ScriptTimeoutException: script timeout
(Session info: chrome=101.0.4951.64)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'frank-ulyana-xfce', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', 
os.version: '5.4.0-110-generic', java.version: '11.0.15'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 101.0.4951.64,     chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 101.0.4951.41 (93c720db8323..., userDataDir:     /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.RjyGbe}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:42731},     javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform:     LINUX, platformName: LINUX, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false,     timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and     notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true,     webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 6d9e43e080e1877deda638b34d533500
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeAsyncScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:506)
at no.husbanken.e2e.rammeverk.selenium.driver.ExtendedWebDriver.isPageReady(ExtendedWebDriver.java:38)
at no.husbanken.e2e.rammeverk.selenium.driver.ExtendedWebDriver.findElement(ExtendedWebDriver.java:56)
at e2e.sak.vedtak.VedtakPage2.velgInnstilling(VedtakPage2.java:24)
at e2e.sak.vedtak.VedtakSteps.jegInnstillerTilAvslag(VedtakSteps.java:87)
```

Any ideas? Short of making the frontend developer revert the changes to a working version, I don't know where to look.

UPDATE:

From the ExtendeWebDriver class in the framework (own project used by the test project):

```
@Override
public WebElement findElement(By by) {
    isPageReady();
    return this.webDriver.findElement(by);
}

@Override
public List<WebElement> findElements(final By by) {
    isPageReady();
    return this.webDriver.findElements(by);
}

....

public void isPageReady() {
    if (teknologi == STARTLAN_ESOKNAD){
        waitUntilAngularReady();
    } else {
        Object response = jsExecutor.executeAsyncScript(venteScript);
        if (response != null) {
            poll(1000);
            response = jsExecutor.executeAsyncScript(venteScript);
            if (response != null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(format("Responsen fra isPageReady() skal alltid være null, men var: %s", response));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The JavaScript executed:

```
private static String getAngularScript() {
    return "function getNg1Hooks(t,e){function n(t){try{if(!e&&angular.getTestability){var n=angular.getTestability(t);if" +
            "(n)return{$$testability:n}}else{var i=angular.element(t).injector();if(i)return{$injector:i}}}catch(t)" +
            "{}}function i(t){for(var e=document.querySelectorAll(t),i=0;i<e.length;i++){var r=n(e[i]);if(r)return r}}if(t)" +
            "return i(t);if(window.__TESTABILITY__NG1_APP_ROOT_INJECTOR__){var r=window" +
            ".__TESTABILITY__NG1_APP_ROOT_INJECTOR__,a=null;try{a=r.get(\"$$testability\")}catch(t){}return{$injector:r," +
            "$$testability:a}}return n(document.body)||i(\"[ng-app]\")||i(\"[ng\\\\:app]\")||i(\"[ng-controller]\")||i" +
            "(\"[ng\\\\:controller]\")}waitForAngular=function(t,e){try{var n=e;if(!window.angular&&!window" +
            ".getAngularTestability)throw new Error(\"both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  " +
            "This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, " +
            "which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details\");!function(e){if" +
            "(window.angular){var n=getNg1Hooks(t);if(n)if(n.$$testability)n.$$testability.whenStable(e);else{if(!n" +
            ".$injector)throw t?new Error(\"root element (\"+t+\") has no injector. this may mean it is not inside ng-app" +
            ".\"):new Error('Could not automatically find injector on page: \"'+window.location.toString()+'\".  Consider " +
            "using config.rootEl');n.$injector.get(\"$browser\").notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(e)}else e()}else e()}" +
            "(function(){if(window.getAngularTestability){if(t){var e=null,i=document.querySelector(t);try{e=window" +
            ".getAngularTestability(i)}catch(t){}if(e)return void e.whenStable(n)}var r=window.getAllAngularTestabilities()" +
            ",a=r.length;if(0===a)return void n();var o=function(){0==--a&&n()};r.forEach(function(t){t.whenStable(o)})" +
            "}else n()})}catch(t){e(t.message)}},waitForAngular(\"body\",arguments[arguments.length-1]);";
}
```

Comment: Its worth to give a try with latest versions of chrome driver and browser. If you have the same issue then definitely it is the locator issue as you mentioned html markup changes.

Comment: Tried with chromedriver 105.

Comment: Do you set this anywhere?:  driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout  It sounds like it's set to something and you do have something in "ExtendedWebDriver" which is calling async script(s).   Maybe include the code for ExtendedWebDriver.  In general it's a very bad idea to check for readystate as you can't know when exactly it will run.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've included some code from the ExtendedWebDriver class. It seems that the findElement(s) methods are overridden with a call to the isPageReady() method. Could it be that this "crashes" with an existing internal pageReady() method, or some other place?

Comment: Hello , apparently with the changes on html/markup there are some resource in the getAngularScript() method should be modified as well . I am not assuming anything here , just try to spot the differences . you can verify if the ChromeDriver is compatible with your chrome version so no updates happened to your browser  because it could be a reason for selenium failure

Comment: I would get rid of those "isPageReady();" calls...  if you want to keep them, you might set a specific ScriptTimeout to see if it helps.  ("driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout...")  Instead of checking readystate, you can use Selenium's WebDriverWait along with an expectedCondition... (i.e. "Explicit Wait").  Handle stale element exceptions if needed.   (Selenium has added some useful expected conditions to deal with stale element exceptions, too.)

Comment: I'll try that. I know Selenium has added some useful things in version 4 - upgrading is in the pipeline :-)

Comment: Have you tried this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63798832/error-org-openqa-selenium-scripttimeoutexception-script-timeout